# How to get Image URL from a ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have no idea how to get an **Image URL** from already settled **ImageView**. Actually, I have an **ImageView** over which picture is set from a **URL**. Now I have a **button** on that **button_clik** I have to fetch that **ImageView URL**. Is it possible or not ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rustam I said, I have no idea, So i did not try to do this.

Comment: is it single Image or is it in ListView??? if there are lots of Images then save it into ArrayList and onClick on button get Image URL

Answer (score 1):

u cannot get the image url from the imageview...infact u will have to use the alternate. For example u might be saving the urls for the imageview in some array...u need to get the position of the imageview clicked and using that position u can get the url of the clicked image...if u r using listview/gridview it is very easy to get the position but if not, u can set the pos as tag of image and retrieve the tag that will specify the position.

if u need help feel free to ask...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't get **URL** from **ImageView**. What you can do is you can store the **URL** in variable or **SharedPreference** when you are setting image in **ImageView** so next time when you want to fetch **URL** you can directly get it  from variable or **SharedPreference**.

Comment: There are lots of images. To whom I should store in SharedPreferences or variables.

Comment: So for the lots of images there would be lots of **ImageViews** also?? isn't it or not. Are you using **ListView** to show images???

Answer (score -6):

By Using Picasso Lib
Picasso.with(contxt).load(imageurl).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(imageview);

Comment: This is for loading into imageview, OP doesn't want this.

Comment: Sorry..but what do you want exactly.

Comment: Read the question again