# How to share image through inten

Tags: java, android

```
 Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();`
 cardView=(CardView)findViewById(R.id.card);
 final String query = intent.getString("Query1");

 db = new DataBaseHelper(Image.this);    
 Cursor c = db.getData(query);
   if (c.getCount() != 0) {
       c.moveToFirst();
       do {
           image = c.getString(5);
           title=c.getString(3);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }   
    txt.setText(title);
    img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(image, "drawable", getPackageName())));
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an Share Intent for image, you can use following code.

`uriToImage` is `Uri` of your image file.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

> EDIT - To get URI of drawable image

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.here/drawable/image_name");
```

Comment: how to get uriToImage for imageview

Comment: See this post for that answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558021/how-to-get-image-url-from-a-imageview

Comment: i am using sqlite database image stored string name and iam getting image to "drawable " .iam listing image in inage view  but cannot share image through intent my code:

Comment: img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(image, "drawable", getPackageName())));

Comment: this img view clik to share inten through intent

Comment: to help for any  idea for get image uri

Answer (score 0):

Use Content Provider(FileProvider) To Share Data as it is Good Practice.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  final String path = "Your File Path";
  Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(YourActivity.this, "com.abc.xy.appname.fileprovider", new File(path));
  intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
   startActivity(intent);
```

For Multiple File Sharing

```
ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mfileList.size(); i++) {
                File file = new File(mfileList.get(i).get_path());
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(YourActivity.this, "com.abc.xy.appname.fileprovider", file);
                files.add(uri);
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
                startActivity(intent);
```

To Share an Image Stored in Your Drawable.Put this Uri in your Share Intent Extras.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package/drawable/image_name");
```

Check this Link out For Content Provider Setup.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider][1]